# Where is bash globbing behavior documented?

Tags: bash, glob

I know I can do the following:

```
ls /dir/*/subdir/file
```

to list any matching files in any matching directories. Is this just regular globbing? It feels like it is more advanced than the following usage:

```
ls /dir/subdir/file*
```

I think of it as "branching/searching glob". If it is different to regular globbing, what is its real name and where is its behaviour documented?

Answer (score 2):

`man bash`

search for `Pathname Expansion`

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular distinction between these two forms in the bash documentation; they're both described under [Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) and [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

Answer (score 0):

It's on the bash man page, in the section on Pattern Matching.

> * Matches any string, including the null string.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to be more portable [here are the POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03).